# what is the difference between "r" and .read() in Python?

Tags: python, split

I want to open a text file and use  `split`

Here is the code I wrote at first:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as file:
 file.split("\n")
```

and here is another code I wrote because the first code I wrote didn't work:

```
txt=open("test.txt")
file=txt.read()
file.split("\n")
```

what is the difference between `"r"` and `.read()`?

Comment: `r` is a letter and `read` is a function.

Comment: You are comparing apples with bananas. what is your actual problem?

Comment: Also, the `r` missing in the second code has nothing to do with the fact that the first didn't work. Hint: Read the error message you'd have received.

Comment: the `'r'` argument to `open` makes no difference in the two code snippets. Indeed, `'r'` is already the default argument: `open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.read()` function is for **reading** data from a file; So the file should be in **read mode** and the read mode is `'r'` that you asked.

So `'r'`is **Mode for File** and `.read()` is a function for **reading data**.

Answer (score 0):

`read()` is the actual function that does the reading of any "path-like object," returning a "file-like object" (this is due to the principle of duck typing). You can optionally pass it a parameter, which is a single character, indicating what "mode" to open the path-like object. Look at the signature for `read():`

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

You can see that the default mode is 'r', thus, if you do not specify a mode, it will default to 'r' anyways, so including 'r' as you did is generally redundant.

[The documentation is here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 0):

The `r`, You can think of it as the purpose of opening a file. if you open a file with `r`, and then you can't do write with the handler! You should got some error as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IOError: File not open for writing
```

`read()` just a way which you can got your data from file handler! there are also have `readline()` available.